# How does the Heart Of Azeroth azerite reduction work?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If I have 90% of a level, and the week resets will I gain a level? or does the ratio stay the same and the amount overall is reduced?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every week the amount of azerite required to reach the next level is reduced by 30%.  The amount of azerite power you currently have is also reduced by 30% so that you remain at the same percentage towards your next level on the Tuesday reset.

For example, let's say you end the week at 700/1000 (70%) azerite power.  When Tuesday rolls around, you will find yourself at 490/700 (70%) azerite power.

As a result, it is good strategy to save as many azerite power turn-ins as possible until the reset to avoid the 30% reduction.

Comment: Thank you! So does that mean the overall experience for every level is reduced as well? So when I level my alt, the overall amount of experience will be greatly reduced from level 1?

Comment: Exactly. They implemented this as a "catch up" mechanic that prevents new characters from falling far behind.